# Construct a full rank matrix by adding vectors from the standard basis

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I have a nxn singular matrix. I want to add k rows (which must be from the standard basis e1, e2, ..., en) to this matrix such that the new (n+k)xn matrix is full column rank. The number of added rows k must be minimum and they can be added in any order (not just e1, e2 ,..., it can be e4, e10, e1, ...) as long as k is minimum.

Does anybody know a simple way to do this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the method you are using to test rank?

Comment: In matlab, I check if rank(A) is equal to n, where A is my matrix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by doing a [QR decomposition with column pivoting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition#Column_pivoting), then taking the transpose of the last `n-rank(A)` columns of the permutation matrix.
In matlab, this is achieved by the `qr` function(See the matlab documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/qr.html)):

```
r=rank(A);
[Q,R,E]=qr(A);
newA=[A;transpose(E(:,end-r+1:end))];
```

Each row of `transpose(E(:,end-r+1:end))` will be a member of standard basis, rank of `newA` will be n, and this is also the minimal number of standard basis you will need to do so.

Here is how this works:

QR decomposition with column pivoting is a standard procedure to decompose a matrix A into products:

A*E==Q*R

where Q is an [orthogonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix) if A is real, or an unitary matrix if A is complex; R is [upper triangular matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_triangular_matrix), and E is a [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix).

In short, the permutations are chosen so that the diagonal elements are larger than the off-diagonals in the same row, and that size of the diagonal elements are non-increasing. More detailed description can be found on the [netlib QR factorization page](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node42.html).

Since Q and E are both orthogonal (or unitary) matrices, the rank of R is the same as the rank of A.  To bring up the rank of A, we just need to find ways to increase the rank of R; and this is much more straight forward thanks to the structure of R as the result of pivoting and the fact that it is upper-triangular.

Now, with the requirement placed on pivoting procedure, if any diagonal element of R is 0, the entire row has to be 0.  The `n-rank(A)` rows of 0s in the bottom if R is responsible for the nullity.  If we replace the lower right corner with an identity matrix, the that new matrix would be full rank.  Well, we cannot really do the replacement, but we can append the rows matrix to the bottom of R and form a new matrix that has the same rank:

```
B==[ 0 I ]     =>   newR=[ R ; B ]
```

Here the dimensionality of `I` is the nullity of A and that of R.
It is readily seen that `rank(newR)=n`.    Then we can also define a new unitary Q matrix by expanding its dimensionality in a trivial manner:

```
newQ=[Q 0 ; 0 I]
```

With that, our new rank n matrix can be obtained as

```
newA=newQ*newR.transpose(E)=[Q*R ; B ]*transpose(E) =[A ; B*transpose(E)]
```

Note that B is `[0 I]` and E is a permutation matrix, so `B*transpose(E)` is simply the transpose
of the last `n-rank(A)` columns of E, and thus a set of rows made of standard basis, and that's just what you wanted!

Answer (score 3):

Is n very large? The simplest solution without using any math would be to try adding e_i and seeing if the rank increases. If it does, keep e_i. proceed until finished.

Comment: Thank you. If e_i and e_j (i<j) both increase rank, can we be sure that both provide the posibility of obtaining the same minimum k? Isn't there a chance that after adding e_i we will need 4 more rows to obtain full rank, while after adding e_j we will need 3 more rows to obtain full rank?

Comment: @user3071889: no, that can't be. the added vector is either linearly dependend on the existing column vectors or not. if it is, it can't add anything, if it isn't, it will increase the rank by 1. standard basis vectors are mutually linearly independent, it doesn't matter which of them you use to increase rank. You will always need exactly n - rank A additional vectors, if A is the original matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I like @Xiaolei Zhu's solution because it's elegant, but another way to go (that's even more computationally efficient is):

1. Determine if any rows, indexed by `i`, of your matrix `A` are all zero.  If so, then the corresponding `e_i` must be concatenated.
2. After that process, you can simply concatenate *any* subset of the `n - rank(A)` columns of the identity matrix that you didn't add in step 1.

Comment: Thank you all very much. This helps me a lot.

Answer (score -1):

rows/cols from Identity matrix can be added in any order. it does not need to be added in usual order as e1,e2,... in general situation for making matrix full rank.

Comment: @ m7913d to make a matrix full rank you can add e1 e2...in any order but the dimension of new added matrix should be n -rank. If i am wrong please let me know.